# Was Princess Leia's hair natural (from Carrie Fisher)?

Tags: star-wars

Princess Leia had some really intense hairstyling, requiring a *lot* of natural hair.

Among other pictures:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Was this Carrie Fisher's real hair in the movies?

Comment: Also, credit where it's do, what I'm recalling may relate to real-world application of such styles, not if her Movie 'do was done with Carrie's hair or not.  See [this article](http://www.deliberatepixel.com/2010/07/16/mythbusting-princess-leia-s-hair) for an In Universe / practical evaluation

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Y2LvtMj.jpg - Extensions, dude

Comment: According to [this account](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/patricia-zohn/princess-leia-explains-it_b_34304.html) of her "one woman show", she openly states that her hair in SW was a wig

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It was definitely not her real hair. This is how long her real hair was[image]

[image]

Comment: More evidence, if you want to improve your answer:  http://skepchick.org/2010/07/mythbusting-princess-leias-hair      
http://noel-duan.tumblr.com/post/120294841806/beauty-and-the-geek-star-wars-inspired-braids-at       http://www.thisisnotporn.net/tag/star-wars/      
Audition tape http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kCXrGuLix7M      
During filming ESB - http://i.imgur.com/9VQCmdT.jpg      
During filming RotJ  - http://static5.imagecollect.com/preview/560/1b4a19d1625ef54

Comment: @WadCheber - Some good finds, especially the last pic

Comment: I admit my defeat! :-)

Answer (score -2):

According to this [source](http://www.hellocoton.fr/to/19tDw#http://www.ninapeople.com/carrie-fisher-sest-coupe-les-cheveux-fini-les-macarons-princesse-leia/155314/):

Carrie Fisher explained at a fan convention in Los Angeles that it took her two hours before each scene for her hair and makeup, while in a parody for Saturday Night Live a simple wig was enough! She said she was upset!

So it was Carrie Fisher's real hair in the movies.

Comment: That's not what it says. It just states that it took two hours to do her hair for the movie. There's no mention of whether it was her hair or extensions or why it took so long.

Comment: She said : "they put me a hairpiece , and it was exactly the same. I was upset". For me it's clear, but you always can interpret as you like.

Comment: I took it to mean "They put me in a dime-store leia wig rather than spending hours plaiting in hair extensions, then styling my hair".

Comment: Ok, I respect your interpretation!